# Issue while doing git push from jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to push some changes(adding a file) in a git repo, using jenkins pipeline.
Here i have the groovy script which is doing this,

```
stage('push template') {
            steps {
                script{
                    try {
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credId', passwordVariable: 'Password', usernameVariable: 'Username')]) {
                            sh("git config credential.username ${env.Username}")
                            sh("git config credential.helper '!f() { echo password=\$Password; }; f'")
                            sh("git add .")
                            sh("git commit -m \"adding config file}\"")
                            sh("GIT_ASKPASS=true git push -v origin {remoteBranchName}")
                        }
                    } finally {
                        sh("git config --unset credential.username")
                        sh("git config --unset credential.helper")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

it breaks while pushing the changes at "git push",

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code
fatal: unable to access 'repo_url': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Any suggestions would help, thanks

For info: The remote branch is not restricted

Comment: By `{remoteBranchName}` you mean a variable? And did you get a chance to check [Jenkins pipeline example to push tags, branch to git repo](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#push-git-repo)

Comment: @vijay, {remoteBranchName}  is not a variable, it is just a indication, there i am passing the actual remote branch name which i have. I am following the same Url you have mentioned. I feel jenkins is not allowed to push the changes in gitlab. so checking for this.